# Too many Python processes running

Tags: python, process, system-monitor

I am running ubuntu 10.10, and everything is working fine. I just checked the system monitor to see what processes run in a linux system..and noticed something strange. There were many python processes running (status:-sleeping)...Why is this? Also each of them seem to use a moderate amount of RAM...

I used to program with python..and then I thought may be it is because of improper closing of the python program.but I restarted the laptop and checked the system monitor but with no change. I have included a screenshot of the system monitor below.
[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They are normal i guess,type `ps x | grep python` in terminal to find out what it is.It may be some applets or programs running in your system.

**This is my output:**

```
karthick@Ubuntu-desktop:~$ ps x | grep python
 2133 ?        S      0:10 python /usr/share/stackapplet/stackapplet.py
 2134 ?        S      0:01 python /usr/share/system-config-printer/applet.py
 9988 pts/0    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto python
```